# no operator "<<" matches these operand

Tags: c++, c++14, stdmap, stdlist

I'm trying to print the value inside the map named as GameMap.

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<int,std::list<int>>>GameMap;
```

However, I keep getting these errors:

```
 no operator matches these operands            operand types are: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> << std::map<int, std::list<int, std::allocator<int>>, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::list<int, std::allocator<int>>>>>
```

Here is the part of the code:

```
 for (int y = 0; y <= 3; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= 4; x++)
    {
        int target_x, target_y;
        target_x = x - 1 + int(round(50/ChunkSize * 32));
        target_y = y - 1 + int(round(50 / ChunkSize * 32));
        std::string key = std::to_string(target_x) + ";" + std::to_string(target_y);
       
        //Check if the key is already on the map 
        std::map<std::string, std::map<int, std::list<int>>>::iterator hint = GameMap.lower_bound(key);
        if (hint == GameMap.end() || GameMap.key_comp()(key, hint->first))
        {
            GameMap.insert(hint, make_pair(key, GenerateChunk(x, y)));
        }
        else {
            hint->second = GenerateChunk(x, y);
        }

       
        for (std::map<std::string, std::map<int, std::list<int>>>::iterator itr = GameMap.begin(); itr != GameMap.end(); ++itr)
        {
            std::cout << itr->first << "-" << itr->second;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have no built in function to print an std::map<int std::list<int>> in cpp, try investigate in this perspective

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory. You cannot use `<<` to print an entire `std::map`. (The value inside your map is another map).

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your own `operator<<` for your map type:

```
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using game_map_value_t = std::map<int, std::list<int>>;
using game_map_t = std::map<std::string, game_map_value_t>;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const game_map_value_t& game_map_val) {
    for (const auto& [key, num_list] : game_map_val) {
        os << "{ " << key << " :";
        for (auto n : num_list) {
            os << " " << n;
        }
        os << " }";
    }
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    game_map_t GameMap = { 
        {"foo", {{5, {1,2,3}}, {1, {500,600,700}}}}, 
        {"bar", {{6, {2,4,6}}, {17, {5000,6000,7000}}}} 
    };
    for (game_map_t::iterator itr = GameMap.begin(); itr != GameMap.end(); ++itr) {
        std::cout << itr->first << "-" << itr->second << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```